# PIP failing to download, can PYcharm load downloaded packages

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I’m having problems installing three packages using PIP; I have been able to do so via the CLI but need to do so via PYcharm.

To explain my environment, I’m on a 64 bit windows desktop running Python 3.7; when I go into Python the startup banner states the following:-

```
“Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.”
```

The message suggests it is a 64 bit package but does ‘on win32’ suggest I’ve got it running at a different level?

Question 1; Is this a problem and if so how can I change it?

Regarding the three packages I’m having problems downloading they are imutils, opencv-contrib-python and numpy, all failing with the same errors:-

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection 
broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read 
timeout=15)")': /simple/numpy/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package> (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for <package>’
```

I’ve got a temporary workaround to download and PIP install locally the packages below via CLI

```
imutils-0.5.3.tar.gz

numpy-1.16.5+vanilla-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

opencv_python-4.1.1+contrib-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Question 2: Can I get this software loaded into PYcharm or is there something else I should be doing within PYcharm?

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with downloads timing out before but I kept trying and all three packages eventually downloaded. That's 10 hours of my life I'll never get back!